# "Account Data Extension" with Account ID as proimary Key using for Order related Emails?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, filters

I created a "Account Data Extension" with AccountID as primary key, so every customer is just ones in the Data Extension.
Now I want to send order related Emails/Journeys. Therefore I filter this Data Extension with Fields of my "Order Data Extension". But what happens when a customer has more than one order? Is this customer than twice in the filtered Data Extension?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible because `Contacts` can belong in multiple `Account` object records as there is a many-to-many relationship between those two objects. You'll have to run a SQL query if you want unique values or you can set the primary key on the Email Address and re-run the filter but that gives you less control on what records you will be selecting to be the unique value.

[image: Relationship Diagram in Salesforce]